# A way to save HTML results via JS

Tags: javascript, android, pdf

I've made a JavaScript Web app to compute something based on a HTML form. It must run well on all modern Web browsers and most used mobile devices, so I did this using Bootstrap 3, no problem here, but the app is returning a page with the results, and other data, and I can't seem to figure out how to make possible the ability to save those results on all mobile devices + desktop PCs.

Here's what I have tried so far:

1. I've tried to generate a print screen of the page and from what I've read, this can't be done using only JavaScript. So dead end here.
2. Right now I am using [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to create a PDF with the results, this works well on everything, but when it comes to the download button, it only works on desktop and iOS. On the default browser of Android (version under 4.4) it doesn't seem to be working. Nothing happens and the problem is general (again, from what I've read). Blob.js related.
3. I've tried to use [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/) to show the generated PDF to the user. This plugin has a download button so that's the main reason I considered using this. But I still have one problem, ViewerJS needs a path to a PDF file on disk to work and jsPDF does not create one, it just creates a URI path (I hope that's what it's called), like so: data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjM... (a very long URI). And I don't know how to make ViewerJS load the PDF from that URI rather than from a file on disk.

I'm looking for a solution to one of those, but also new suggestions.

I really hope somebody can help me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HTML5 canvas and let the user download the results as image/png. Download option for images is available on most modern browsers both on mobile and desktop.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>

function update() {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = 300;
    canvas.height = 300;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#dddddd";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.font = "20px Helvetica";
    ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("text").value, 100, 100);

    document.getElementById("img").src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="text" onkeyup="update()" />
    <img id="img" />
</body>
```